# Replacing info in HTML page using PHP before rendering

Tags: php, compilation, phpstorm, intellij-14, string-substitution

EDIT: After typing this out I think this approach is a non starter.  All I am trying to do is to find an easier way to type `<?=` and `?>` in longish HTML pages. Any ideas greatly appreciated.
**LATER:** Yep this **is** a non-starter so I am tweaking my IDE (the wonderful PhpStorm) to take care of this and will probably start using Twig "soon".

==============================

I find endless typing of `<?=`  `=>` an absolute nightmare. For some reason I really cannot remember position of the keys on keyboard and get confused on the shift/nonshift (brain aged 64 and/or too much cannabliss in my youth?) and have to search for them every time and do things like just now I typed a <kbd>+</kbd>  instead of a <kbd>=</kbd>!

I don't want to use a full-on templating engine like Moustache yet but just want to replace the `<?=` and  `=>` with something like `{{{` `}}}`.

To experiment I am using `jjjj` and `kkk`.

To try and do this I put the whole HTML page into a HEREDOC variable called $mypage. At present there is only one replacement target but this will obviously go into a loop if I can get it working.

```
  $start = strpos($myPage, "jjjj");
  $end = strpos($myPage, "kkk");

  substr_replace($myPage,"<?=$",$start,4);
  substr_replace($myPage,"?> ",$end, 3);

  $insName = "Boo";


  echo $myPage;
```

In the HTML I have:

```
<label for="clientFirstName">First name* jjjjinsNamekkk</label>
```

The `echo` works fine and displays the page properly but the strings are **not** replaced. Worse than that I think I may be just completely wrong.

If I replace the `jjjj` in the body with `<?=$` will that be interpreted or just `echoed` as text to the screen?

Also given that I tend to use includes quite a lot would they work in this echo/HEREDOC strategy? I suspect not.

Grateful for any suggestions.

PS Yes I know this is all a terrible way of doing things but this is for an alpha for LITERALLY about 10 people so I am just doing a quick and dirty. (Which to be honest is the only way I program these days!)

Comment: Of course this will only get displayed - you are working on _data_ here, not _code_. If you wanted to get that data interpreted as code again, you would have to send it through `eval` (which is not that recommendable - go read up on it, if you don’t know why.)

Comment: `Twig` template engine.

Comment: @u_mulder looked at Twig, just had a second look might well be within my reach but at present not understanding the install on remote server but suspect not too horrible. Thanks for the reminder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your (edited) question is the sort of thing your IDE or enhanced editor would usually do for you. From what I can glean, it appears you use PHPStorm. You could use a [Live Template](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2018/01/using-and-creating-code-snippets/) for this. There are some pre-defined ones for PHP but I don't think what you're after is there.

For example, to create one to insert the whole of `<?= ?>`

- Type `<?=$END$ ?>` into the editor ($END$ positions the cursor)
- Highlight the above text
- ctrl-shift-a / cmd-shift-a (as appropriate for your operating system)
- Type 'save as' into the popup and select 'Save as Live Template'
- Enter a suitable abbreviation, e.g. 'pie' (PHP Inline Expression)
- Edit template text if necessary
- Click Apply

Thereafter you can type 'pie' followed by the tab key into the editor to insert the text.

Comment: I swear I will forget my own liver soon!  

I am having a look at Twig again - may have a go at that tonight but the beloved PhpStorm once again comes to the rescue. .... PAUSE .... It embarrasses me to say that I already had a Live Template  (`<<` was my chosen abbreviation with the string `<?=$END$?>`). I still would prefer the straightforward substitution for readability if nothing else.   PS I had not some across the 'Save as Live Template' before - very useful. I do have one last wish - for the template to be `<?=$ ?>` with the `$` escaped. but I cannot make that work.

Comment: See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207036935-Escaping-Dollar-Sign-in-Live-Template